# get first record from each day then only check condition

Tags: mysql

I have user attendance CLOCK IN data like this.

```
id  | userID | created_at
1   | 1      | 2018-06-27 00:15:00
2   | 1      | 2018-06-27 01:43:55
3   | 1      | 2018-06-27 02:43:55
4   | 2      | 2018-06-27 00:15:00
5   | 2      | 2018-06-27 02:43:55
6   | 2      | 2018-06-27 03:43:55
7   | 1      | 2018-06-28 00:55:00
8   | 1      | 2018-06-28 01:43:55
9   | 1      | 2018-06-28 02:43:55
10  | 2      | 2018-06-28 00:00:00
11  | 2      | 2018-06-28 02:43:55
12  | 2      | 2018-06-28 03:43:55
```

I want a list of dates where user was late to clock in.
Assume company work time is 00:00:00 and 
How can I get results like this :

```
id  | userID | created_at
1   | 1      | 2018-06-27 00:15:00
4   | 2      | 2018-06-27 00:15:00
7   | 1      | 2018-06-28 00:55:00
```

Appreciate any help from you guys.Thanks

Comment: Please tell us why you expect those 3 records?  Which constitutes a late clock in, and what would an on-time clock in look like?

Comment: Hi tim, i wan to get late clock for each day. On time clock in would be 00:00:00 everyday

Comment: however one user might have multiple clock in each day like clock in after lunch time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try conditionally aggregating by user and date, and then checking to see whether an exact midnight clock in occurred (or did not occur):

```
SELECT
    userID,
    MIN(created_at) AS created_at
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    userID,
    DATE(created_at)
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%H:%i:%s') = '00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Hi tim, do you know why mysql return me error "AS created_at
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%H:%i:%s') = '00" ?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS created_at
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%H:%i:%s') = '00' at line 7"

Comment: @shalonteoh Sorry, I had a typo in there.  Difficult to write a complex query correctly the first time, without any testing.  Reload your page.